# Failed to launch iTerm2

Tags: macos, iterm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iTerm2 terminals close immediately with “argpath=login error=No such file or directory”](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50752/iterm2-terminals-close-immediately-with-argpath-login-error-no-such-file-or-dir)

iTerm2 is immediately closed after launch with the error:

```
"argpath=login error=No such file or directory"
```

If I switch from login to command (with bash -l) I'm getting the following error:

```
"argpath=bash error=No such file or directory"
```

I'm running OSX Lion.

How this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is some problem with reading whatever iTerm2 reads as a login shell.  Try changing the preference in 'Profiles/General' to a specific command (i.e. `/bin/bash`) and see if that works.

Additionally, does Apple's terminal work?  could you do something like

```
echo $SHELL
bash
```

and see if bash actually exists on your machine?  Bash is quite unfussed on what login items you have, so make sure you have a minimal .bash_profile and .bashrc in your $HOME

Give it a try and let's see if we get enough info to help you.

Comment: I have this in my .bashrc: $ cat .bashrc
export TERM=xterm-256color

Comment: also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788402/error-opening-terminal-xterm-256color

Comment: and at: http://superuser.com/questions/327791/terminal-strangeness-after-installing-xcode-on-lion

Comment: It seems that /bin is no longer in my path so the command should be /bin/bash instead of bin. How can I fix this?